# Перегрузка операции

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, операции

Началась новая тема и я никак не могу понять, что требуется и как это реализовать на практике.
Если кто-нибудь сможет разъяснить, показать пример(с комментариями), буду очень благодарен.

Задание 1. Унарная операция
Создать объект стек, перегрузив ++ и --. (Как постфиксными так префиксными). ++ Добавляет элемент в стек. -- извлекает элемент из стека.
Задание 2. Бинарная операция
Создать объект очередь с перегруженными +, +=, добавление элемента в очередь и сложение очередей, -- для извлечения из очереди, - для вычитания очередей.

Comment: Что требуется Вам написано. Как реализовать погуглите "перегрузка операций". Что именно непонятно-то?

Comment: Непонятно - "Создать объект стек, перегрузив ++ и --. (Как постфиксными так префиксными). ++ Добавляет элемент в стек. -- извлекает элемент из стека."

Само "перегрузка" - понял

Comment: Так, хорошо. Что такое перегрузка Вам известно. Тогда какой из терминов не понятен? Стек? Постфиксный/префиксный? ++/--?

Comment: Стек и как его перезагружать. Просто, объясните, если не сложно

Comment: Вам не нужно "перезагружать стек". Вам нужно перегрузить операции в стеке. Гуглите "что такое структура данных стек". Про перегрузку Вы уже знаете. Всё, вопрос решён.